# insert jquery in wordpress page

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a jquery script I'd like to insert into a wordpress page.
The script choose random GIF to show in a div. You can see it here : http://tstand.net/surfaceid_wp/wp-content/themes/surfaceid/test.html
So I know this is working. I've tried to follow the advices about some topics but nothing seems to work. So if anyone can help, I'll really appreciate.

the code on the page is :

HTML :

```
<div id="slider-gif"></div>
```

CSS :

```
.fadeIn{
  -webkit-animation: fade-in 2s ease;
  -moz-animation: fade-in ease-in-out 2s both;
  -ms-animation: fade-in ease-in-out 2s both;
  -o-animation: fade-in ease-in-out 2s both;
  animation: fade-in 2s ease;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0;} 100%{opacity:1;}}
@-moz-keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0} 100%{opacity:1}}
@-o-keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0} 100%{opacity:1}}
@keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0} 100%{opacity:1}}

#slider-gif { width:800px; height:500px; background-color:yellow; overflow:hidden; margin: 0 auto;}
img { width:100%; height:auto;}
```

the javascript file :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var images = ['curring.gif', 'helmit.gif', 'quiver.gif'];
        $('<img class=" afade-in" src="images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + '">').appendTo('#slider-gif');
});
```

I put the javascript file into the wordpress folder /js/gif.js
And into the functions.php of the Wordpress theme I put :

```
/* Enqueue scripts (and related stylesheets) */
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_nifty_scripts' );
/**
 * Registers scripts for the theme and enqueue those used site wide.
 *
 * @since 0.1.0.
 */

function my_nifty_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('gif', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'js/gif.js', false, null, true);
if(is_page('Page-Home')){
    wp_enqueue_script('gif'); 
}}
```

I don't know what I have to do to fix this

Comment: Your script requires jQuery as a dependency, but you did not specify it as such in your `wp_register_script()` or `wp_enqueue_script()` line—see how to use them: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script and https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: test page throws  500 error trying to access jQuery.js. Can see it in browser dev tools network. Strange for a script file to create a 500 so possibly related to htaccess

Comment: The page should be working now.

I check the page @Terry, and If my understandings are right, I put this code, but nothing change : 

`/* Enqueue scripts (and related stylesheets) */
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_random_scripts' );

function load_random_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('load-gif', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/load-slider-gif.js');
if(is_page('home')){
    wp_enqueue_script('load-gif', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/load-slider-gif.js'); 
}}`

Comment: the latest code is working, it appeared it was the update of a wordpress theme which show a white screen where it was supposed to be the images. Thanks for your help everyone